# Unity Coroutine for gameMenu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game like the roll a ball game on the tutorials in the Unity website, now I'm focused on the gameover menu, when the player lose all his lives I activate the gameover text, the yes and no text and the rawImage that is displayed behind the yes text by default, the thing is I want the image that is behind the yes text to go down to no and up to yes with the arrow keys. I think I implemented it right with the keys, but I feel like I need a coroutine to build this, because it just leaves the gameover function, without waiting the user input, so after this how can I build this in a right mode?

I did this at the moment:

```
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour {

private float checkPoint = 0;
public GameObject Ball;
private GameObject cam;
private Object newBall;
public int lifes;
public Text Lifetext;
private bool gameIsOver = false;
private Text gameOver;
private Text playAgain;
private Text yes;
private Text no;
private RawImage TopMenuBall;


void Awake(){
    Lifetext = GameObject.Find("Lifes").GetComponent<Text>();
    gameOver = GameObject.Find("GameOver").GetComponent<Text>();
    playAgain = GameObject.Find("PlayAgain").GetComponent<Text>();
    yes = GameObject.Find("Yes").GetComponent<Text>();
    no = GameObject.Find("No").GetComponent<Text>();
    TopMenuBall = GameObject.Find("TopMenuBall").GetComponent<RawImage>();

    gameOver.enabled = false;
    playAgain.enabled = false;
    yes.enabled = false;
    no.enabled = false;
    TopMenuBall.enabled = false;
    TopMenuBall.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-68,-41,0);

}

void Start(){
    lifes = 3;
    Lifetext.text = " x" + lifes;
    SpawnBall ();
    cam = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera");

}

public void LifeUp(){
    lifes++;
    Lifetext.text = "X " + lifes; 
}

public void LifeDown(){
    if (lifes <= 0) {
        GameOver ();
    } else {
        lifes--;
        Lifetext.text = "X " + lifes;
    }
}

public void GameOver(){
    Debug.Log ("gameover");
    gameOver.enabled = true;
    playAgain.enabled = true;
    yes.enabled = true;
    no.enabled = true;
    TopMenuBall.enabled = true;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        TopMenuBall.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (-68, -82, 0);
        Debug.Log ("up");
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        TopMenuBall.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-68,-41,0);
}

void SpawnBall(){
    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 (0.02f,1.4f,-39f);
    Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    newBall = Instantiate (Ball, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
    Camera.main.GetComponent<cameraMove>().player = (GameObject)newBall;
}
```

when the user lose all the lifes it enters the gameover function and there is the problem, how can I solve this?

Comment: why corotine? you can just use `Vector3.Lerp` to just move the image.

Comment: i want to do it on my manger, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) method to get the user inputs. Because you need it to be constantly checked and the Update method exists exactly for this kind of situation, once it is called every frame.

So, your code should look like this:

```
void Update() {
    if (TopMenuBall.enabled) {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
            TopMenuBall.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (-68, -82, 0);
            Debug.Log ("up");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            TopMenuBall.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-68,-41,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for that answer, it makes sense, but just 1 last question, for example i want what is inside that Update function to run just when it is gameover and in that case, if it works every frame even when it is not gameover it works

Comment: That is why I added the "if (TopMenuBall.enabled)" command. This way this input will be checked only when it is enabled(that I saw you enable only at the GameOver function). You could another variable as well, maybe create a boolean that you will set only at the right time.

Comment: i did it friend, thank you very much for your help :)